# Jersey GET param returning null

Tags: json, jakarta-ee, jersey

I am new to Java EE, and am attempting to write a GET service. To get a value from the webservice, I need to send the primary key to the service as a parameter. I am getting a null on the parameter value at the server end. I know I am missing something basic here.

Client Side Junit test

```
//VehicleList
        service = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri(
                "http://localhost:8081/mCruiseOnCarPool4All/carpool4all/VehicleList/Request").build());
        service.setProperty("identityHash", identityHash) ;
        VehicleDetailsConcrete[] vehicleList = service.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(
                VehicleDetailsConcrete[].class);
        assertNotNull(vehicleList) ;
        assertTrue(vehicleList.length > 0) ;
```

Server Side Service

```
@GET
@Path ("Request")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response getVehicleList(@PathParam("identityHash") String identityHash) {
    VehicleListRequest request = new VehicleListRequest(identityHash) ;
    VehicleListResponse response ;
    clientSession = sessionManager.getClientSession(identityHash) ;
    clientSession.getSendQueue().sendRequest(request) ;
    try {
        response = (VehicleListResponse)clientSession.waitAndGetResponse(request) ;
    } catch (WaitedLongEnoughException e) {
        return Response.serverError().build() ;
    } catch (UnableToResolveResponseException e) {
        return Response.serverError().build() ;
    };
    return Response.ok(response).build();
}
```

identityHash in getVehicleList is null

I am using setProperty, assuming it will do a setParam. I am certain that is what I am missing. A setParameter kinda call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong method. [`WebResource.setProperty`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.14/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) ist not used to set query parameters.

I am not sure what you want `identityHash` to be. In your `@GET` method, you use a `@PathParam`. But this method has no `{identityHash}` in the `@Path`.

Because of this, I assume you want to use a `@QueryParam`.

Build your [`URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) including query parameters:

```
URI uri =  new URI("http",
                   null,
                   "localhost",
                   8081,
                   "/mCruiseOnCarPool4All/carpool4all/VehicleList/Request",
                   "identityHash=YourIdentityHash",
                   null);
service = client.resource(uri);
```

**Note**

You are not using J2EE but Java EE. J2EE was the name used prior to Java EE 5.